# Filling Wrappanel with own usercontrol in code

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, user-controls

I'm trying to create a page where you get an overview of the sponsors of the project, the data is fetched from the database with the following service:

```
    [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Sponsor> getSponsors()
    {
        var query = (from p in dc.Sponsors select p);

        IEnumerable<Sponsor> i = query;

        return i;
    }
```

When I put my breakpoint on the i I can see that the data is correctly in there.

In my `Sponsorspage` I do the following

```
public partial class Sponsorspage : UserControl
{
    IEnumerable<Sponsor> sponsors = null;


    public Sponsorspage()
    {
        SponsorsServiceClient client = new SponsorsServiceClient();
        client.getSponsorsCompleted +=new EventHandler<getSponsorsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getSponsorsCompleted);
        client.getSponsorsAsync();

        InitializeComponent();


    }

    void client_getSponsorsCompleted(object sender, getSponsorsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
        else
        {
            sponsors = e.Result;

            foreach (Sponsor s in sponsors)
            {
                SponsorView control = new SponsorView(s.tekst);
                SLWrapPanel.Children.Add(control);
            }
        }
    }
```

For each sponsor in the database, I create the `Sponsorview` to which I give the source and text. You can see the code for my `Sponsorview` here.

```
public partial class SponsorView : UserControl
{
    public SponsorView(string tekst)
    {
        txtSponsor.Text = tekst;

        //Uri uri = new Uri(imageSource, UriKind.Relative);
        //ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        //imgSponsor.Source = imgSource;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

But when I run the page, I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at OndernemersAward.Views.SponsorView..ctor(String tekst)
   at OndernemersAward.Views.Sponsorspage.client_getSponsorsCompleted(Object sender, getSponsorsCompletedEventArgs e)
   at OndernemersAward.SponsorsServiceReference.SponsorsServiceClient.OngetSponsorsCompleted(Object state)
```

What I'm trying to do is give information (here `string tekst`) from the `sponsor s` to my user control, which it then uses to fill a textblock. Am I doing this wrong or?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You will need to turn on SL debugging in your web project.

Comment: According to my visual studio it is enabled. http://localhostr.com/files/B1hcPyS/capture.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're trying to iterate over results that you are supposed to hold in `sponsors` variable. However, please note that you're calling asynchronus version (and the only one available in Silverlight, as I recall) of `getSponsors` method. What it means is, you will not get results immediately after calling service method, but instead you need to wait until event with completed execution will be called.

I don't know why such thing could create some problems with debug, but it's definitely error in code that could result in problems with showing the page.

[Here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=208) is very simple example on how you should retrieve result from service. Hope this will help you notice error in your approach.

Comment: I get what you mean, I think, I managed to fix by putting the code in my 'completed' method, but now I am getting a different error. I editted my initial post. Thank you :)

Comment: I understand that you can now debug code? Which element throws null reference exception? I can only suspect that it is `txtSponsor` element. Is it defined in `xaml`? You should set its `Text` property after calling `InitializeComponent` method, which sets up whole control and initializes data. There is lot of good examples on how to create `UserControl`'s on internet, look through some of them. Also, check some reources on data binding in Silverlight, maybe you can get rid of code behind completly and use `ListBox` or something with `ItemTemplate`? This would make your code much better.